# Wine installation isue after upgrade 12.04 -> 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine

After upgrade 12.004 -> 14.04 (x86_64) I see the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6

wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but it is not
going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-get install liblcms2-2:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas accountsservice-ubuntu-touch-schemas
cli-common digikam-data freeglut3 gir1.2-secret-1 gnome-video-effects
gsettings-ubuntu-touch-schemas gstreamer1.0-nice guile-2.0-libs hddtemp
hugin-data hugin-tools kipi-plugins-common liballegro4.4
liballegro4.4-plugin-alsa libandroid-properties1 libart2.0-cil
libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-serialization1.54.0 libcapnp-0.4.0
libcontent-hub0 libdbus-cpp2 libdee-qt5-3 libfarstream-0.2-2 libgc1c2
libgconf2.0-cil libgdiplus libgexiv2-2 libgflags2 libglade2.0-cil
libglade2.0-cil-dev libglib2.0-cil libglib2.0-cil-dev libgnome-vfs2.0-cil
libgnome2.24-cil libgoogle-glog0 libgsl0ldbl libgtk2.0-cil libgtk2.0-cil-dev
libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkspell0 libhardware2 libhud-client2 libhybris
libhybris-common1 libimage-exiftool-perl libjsoncpp0 libkdcraw-data
libkface-data libkface2 libkgeomap-data libkgeomap1 libkipi-data libkipi11
libksane-data libksane0 liblensfun-data liblensfun0 libmedia1
libmediascanner-2.0-0 libmirclient7 libmirclientplatform-mesa libmirplatform
libmirplatformgraphics-mesa libmirprotobuf0 libmirserver18 libmono-2.0-dev
libmono-accessibility2.0-cil libmono-accessibility4.0-cil
libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-c5-1.1-cil
libmono-cairo2.0-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-cecil-private-cil
libmono-cil-dev libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil
libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil libmono-corlib2.0-cil
libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.5-cil libmono-cscompmgd8.0-cil
libmono-csharp4.0c-cil libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil
libmono-data-tds2.0-cil libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libmono-db2-1.0-cil
libmono-debugger-soft2.0a-cil libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil
libmono-entityframework-sqlserver6.0-cil libmono-entityframework6.0-cil
libmono-http4.0-cil libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil libmono-i18n-mideast4.0-cil
libmono-i18n-other4.0-cil libmono-i18n-rare4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west2.0-cil
libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n2.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-all
libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-ldap2.0-cil libmono-ldap4.0-cil
libmono-management2.0-cil libmono-management4.0-cil
libmono-messaging-rabbitmq2.0-cil libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil
libmono-messaging2.0-cil libmono-messaging4.0-cil
libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil
libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil
libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil
libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil
libmono-microsoft-build2.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil
libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil
libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil libmono-microsoft8.0-cil
libmono-npgsql2.0-cil libmono-npgsql4.0-cil libmono-opensystem-c4.0-cil
libmono-oracle2.0-cil libmono-oracle4.0-cil libmono-parallel4.0-cil
libmono-peapi2.0a-cil libmono-peapi4.0a-cil libmono-posix2.0-cil
libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-rabbitmq2.0-cil libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil
libmono-relaxng2.0-cil libmono-relaxng4.0-cil libmono-security2.0-cil
libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip2.6-cil libmono-sharpzip2.84-cil
libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-simd2.0-cil libmono-simd4.0-cil
libmono-sqlite2.0-cil libmono-sqlite4.0-cil
libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil
libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil
libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil
libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil
libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil libmono-system-data-linq2.0-cil
libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil
libmono-system-data-services2.0-cil libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil
libmono-system-data2.0-cil libmono-system-data4.0-cil
libmono-system-design4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil
libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil
libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil
libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil
libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil
libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil
libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil
libmono-system-json2.0-cil libmono-system-json4.0-cil
libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil libmono-system-ldap2.0-cil
libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil libmono-system-management4.0-cil
libmono-system-messaging2.0-cil libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil
libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil
libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil
libmono-system-net2.0-cil libmono-system-net4.0-cil
libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil
libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil
libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil
libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil
libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil
libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil
libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil
libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil
libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil
libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil
libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil
libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil
libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil
libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil
libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil
libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil
libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil
libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil
libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil
libmono-system-web-mvc1.0-cil libmono-system-web-mvc2.0-cil
libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil
libmono-system-web-routing4.0-cil libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil
libmono-system-web-webpages-deployment2.0-cil
libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil
libmono-system-web2.0-cil libmono-system-web4.0-cil
libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0a-cil
libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil libmono-system-windows4.0-cil
libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil
libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-cil
libmono-system2.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-tasklets2.0-cil
libmono-tasklets4.0-cil libmono-wcf3.0a-cil libmono-web4.0-cil
libmono-webbrowser2.0-cil libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil
libmono-webmatrix-data4.0-cil libmono-windowsbase3.0-cil
libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil libmono-winforms2.0-cil
libmono-xbuild-tasks2.0-cil libmono-xbuild-tasks4.0-cil libmono2.0-cil
libmonoboehm-2.0-1 libmonoboehm-2.0-dev libnatpmp1 libnunit-cil-dev
libnunit2.6-cil libofono-qt1 libois-1.3.0 libonline-accounts-client1
liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 libpano13-2 libpano13-bin libpgf6
libpgm-5.1-0 libprocess-cpp1 libpyzy-1.0-0 libqdjango-db0 libqgsttools-p1
libqmenumodel0 libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test
libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5
libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libqt5xmlpatterns5
libqtassistantclient4 libsilly libsystemsettings1 libtelepathy-farstream3
libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1 libubuntu-application-api1
libubuntu-download-manager-client0 libubuntu-download-manager-common0
libubuntu-download-manager-priv0 libubuntu-location-service0
libubuntu-platform-hardware-api1 libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 libufe-xidgetter0
libunity-api0 libunity-mir1 libunity-scopes1 libunwind8
libusermetricsoutput1 libvigraimpex5 libwebkit1.1-cil
libwhoopsie-preferences0 libzmq3 libzmqpp3 libzthread-2.3-2 libzzip-0-13
mediascanner2.0 mono-4.0-gac mono-csharp-shell mono-devel mono-gac mono-mcs
mono-runtime mono-runtime-common mono-runtime-sgen mono-xbuild monodoc-base
monodoc-browser monodoc-manual mplayerthumbs ofono oneconf-common
packagekit-tools powerd psensor-common python-lxml python-numpy
python-oneconf python-qt4 python-sip python3-brlapi python3-cairo
python3-gi-cairo python3-gnupg python3-louis python3-oneconf
python3-piston-mini-client python3-pyatspi python3-speechd python3-xdg
qmenumodel-qml qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin
qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin qtdeclarative5-folderlistmodel-plugin
qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0 qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin
qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content0.1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components-assets
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets
qtdeclarative5-ubuntuone1.0 qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin
qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin shotwell-common signon-plugin-password
smc-data sqlite3 suru-icon-theme system-image-common system-image-dbus
thumbnailer-service ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-keyboard-data
ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-purchase-service ubuntu-touch-sounds
ubuntuone-client-data ubuntuone-credentials-common unity-plugin-scopes
unity-scope-mediascanner2 unity-scope-scopes unity-webapps-qml
usermetricsservice webapp-container webbrowser-app whoopsie-preferences
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu click click-apparmor
  foomatic-filters gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 gir1.2-json-1.0
  libclick-0.4-0 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 libupstart-app-launch2
  liburcu1 libwebkit1.1-cil monodoc-browser polkit-kde-1 python3-apparmor
  python3-apparmor-click python3-click python3-libapparmor upstart-app-launch
  upstart-app-launch-tools
Suggested packages:
  liblcms2-utils:i386 monodoc-webkit-manual
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  account-plugin-aim account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr
  account-plugin-google account-plugin-identica account-plugin-jabber
  account-plugin-salut account-plugin-twitter account-plugin-windows-live
  account-plugin-yahoo activity-log-manager
  activity-log-manager-control-center aisleriot alacarte apport-gtk apturl
  bamfdaemon baobab bluez-cups brasero brasero-cdrkit cheese colord cups
  cups-core-drivers cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers deja-dup
  deja-dup-backend-gvfs digikam dolphin empathy enblend enfuse eog evince
  evolution-data-server file-roller friends-facebook friends-identica
  friends-twitter gcalctool gcr gedit ghostscript ghostscript-x gimp
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0
  gkbd-capplet gnome-applets gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-contacts
  gnome-control-center gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-icon-theme
  gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-media
  gnome-mines gnome-nettool gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-panel
  gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-flashback
  gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor
  gnome-terminal gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnomine
  gstreamer1.0-clutter gtk3-engines-unico gucharmap gvfs-backends
  gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter
  hplip hugin humanity-icon-theme ibus ibus-gtk3 ibus-pinyin ibus-table
  imagemagick indicator-applet-complete indicator-application
  indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-keyboard indicator-printers
  inkscape kipi-plugins landscape-client-ui-install language-selector-gnome
  libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
  libaccount-plugin-google libappindicator3-1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0
  libbaloowidgets4 libbrasero-media3-1 libcanberra-gtk3-0
  libcanberra-gtk3-module libcdr-0.0-0 libcdr-0.1-1 libcegui-mk2-0.7.6
  libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-2.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libdevil1c2 libevdocument3-4
  libevview3-3 libfolks-eds25 libfreeimage3 libgail-3-0 libgcr-3-1
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-control-center1
  libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnomekbd8
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgrip0 libgs9 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtkmm-3.0-1
  libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgweather-3-6 libgxps2
  libido3-0.1-0 libindicator3-7 libkdcraw23 libkfilemetadata4 liblcms2-2
  libmagick++5 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libmng2
  libnautilus-extension1a libnm-gtk0 libogre-1.8.0 libpanel-applet-4-0
  libpeas-1.0-0 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler-qt4-4 libpoppler19 libpoppler44
  libpstoedit0c2a libqtbamf1 libraw9 libreoffice
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-ru
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans
  libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-presentation-minimizer
  libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-writer
  librhythmbox-core8 libspectre1 libtimezonemap1 libtotem0 libunique-3.0-0
  libunity-2d-private0 libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9
  libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps0 libvte-2.90-9
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwnck-3-0 libyelp0 light-themes mahjongg
  mcp-account-manager-uoa metacity modemmanager monodevelop mousetweaks
  mythes-ru nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share
  nepomuk-core-runtime network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome
  notification-daemon notify-osd okular onboard onboard-data oneconf
  overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 overlay-scrollbar-gtk3 perlmagick
  policykit-1-gnome poppler-utils printer-driver-gutenprint
  printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-pnm2ppa printer-driver-postscript-hp
  printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi
  printer-driver-splix psensor pstoedit python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python-imaging python-pil python-ubuntu-sso-client python-uniconvertor
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-uno remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
  remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
  seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell simple-scan smc smc-music software-center
  software-properties-gtk steam-launcher synaptic system-config-printer-gnome
  telepathy-indicator totem totem-mozilla totem-plugins transmission-gtk
  ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session ubuntu-sso-client
  ubuntu-sso-client-qt unity unity-2d unity-2d-common unity-2d-panel
  unity-2d-shell unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-control-center
  unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-gtk3-module
  unity-lens-applications unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-gdrive
  unity-scope-manpages unity-services unity-settings-daemon
  unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-service update-manager update-notifier
  usb-creator-gtk vino webaccounts-extension-common xdg-user-dirs-gtk
  xdiagnose xerox-phaser-6000-6010:i386 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts
  xul-ext-websites-integration yelp zeitgeist zeitgeist-datahub zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu click click-apparmor
  foomatic-filters gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 gir1.2-json-1.0
  libclick-0.4-0 liblcms2-2:i386 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0
  libupstart-app-launch2 liburcu1 libwebkit1.1-cil monodoc-browser
  polkit-kde-1 python3-apparmor python3-apparmor-click python3-click
  python3-libapparmor upstart-app-launch upstart-app-launch-tools
0 upgraded, 23 newly installed, 326 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 901 kB of archives.
After this operation, 936 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I answered "No", looked like it would be a disaster to confirm.

Note: I have studied this:
[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

but no pieces of advise helped to even detect broken packages.

I would appreciate piece(s) of advise about the above.

Also:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/    dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe    multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe    multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

And

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main #     blocked after upgrade to trusty
# deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free
# deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
```

Answer (score 0):

I just today got Wine working with *Diablo3* under Ubuntu 14.04.  I think the problem may be that you perhaps did not remove the old wine packages / dependencies before attempting to install the new version, or did not run the wine update as an upgrade perhaps?  Also you may want the wine repository as a source.  I can tell you the approach I used:

First run following command in terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>),

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Then update APT package information by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudp apt-get check
sudo-apt-get build-dep wine1.6
```

may you can also try `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

Comment: I followed the sequence you mentioned, but 'build-dep' resulted in 
     wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but it is not
going to be installed

Thus, generally, I just saw exactly the same I posted about.

You mentioned 'remove old Wine packages/dependencies' - how can I verify I did that? I see the above recursion about liblcms2 again and again and can't figure out how to handle it without entire system reinstall.

Comment: Update: testing for older Wine /its dependencies presence didn't find anything in my case.